# how to pass a flag as an argument to grep

Tags: ubuntu, unix, grep

I'm trying to pass -- as an argument to grep because the file I'm interested in contains -- within its text, like so

```
grep -- file.txt
```

but I cannot because grep sees -- as a flag. How do I pass -- as an argument, rather than a flag, to grep?

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -e '--' file.txt
```

From the man page for grep:

```
-e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
     Use PATTERN as the pattern.  This can be used to specify multiple search patterns, or to
     protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen (-).  (-e is specified by POSIX.)
```

Answer (score 1):

At least with GNU grep you can tell it that no more flags are forthcoming with `--`. You can test it like this with a recent version of bash:

```
<<<"--" grep -- --
```

Output:

```
--
```

Comment: whad does <<< do?

Comment: @Maksim: It's the same as saying `echo --`, but lets the shell handle it and avoids portability issues.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the simplest:

```
grep -- -- file
```

The first `--` indicates the end of options. It is typically used when the command you are running has options that start with `-` or `--`, and you want to pass an argument that starts with a `-`.

The second `--` is the string you are searching.

If you wanted to include some more options to grep, those should precede the first `--`, like so:
To match `--` exactly:

```
grep -w -- -- file
```